# My App is crashing in emulator with FATAL EXCEPTION

Tags: android, android-emulator, fatal-error, crash

My App is crashing in the emulator. I looked at logCat and found `FATAL EXCEPTION` in there but I don't know how to solve this. I found similar questions,  but their solution does not solve my issue.  I do not understand what is wrong with my code.

LogCat

```
    --------- beginning of crash
01-03 15:48:12.322    2990-2990/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.dell.firstapp, PID: 2990
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dell.firstapp/com.example.dell.firstapp.Splash}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
            at com.example.dell.firstapp.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:16)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
            at com.example.dell.firstapp.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:16)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 74649612 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2474)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3737)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:497)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:200)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:196)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:192)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
            at com.example.dell.firstapp.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:16)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at ``android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)"
public class Starting extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

TextView display;
Button add, sub;
int counter=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting);
    initialise();
}

private void initialise(){
    display=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisp);
    add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    sub=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);
    sub.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.bAdd:

            counter++;
            display.setText("Your total is "+counter);
            break;
        case R.id.bSub:
            counter--;
            display.setText("Your total is "+counter);
            break;
    }
}
```

}

```
public class Splash extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    Thread timer= new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            try{
                sleep(2000);
            }catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                Intent openStarting= new Intent("com.example.dell.firstapp.STARTING");
                startActivity(openStarting);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}
```

}

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView android:text="Your total is 0"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/tvDisp"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Add one"
        android:id="@+id/bAdd" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="substract one"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/bSub" />


</LinearLayout>

androidMenifest

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dell.firstapp" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Starting"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.dell.firstapp.STARTING" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you post your full logcat

Comment: code nothing tells us when there is no any log

Comment: how to post the logcat ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed the English issues with your post. I have removed the leading >, please use that for error messages or similar.

For others to be able to help you they need to know more.  Please edit the post and add the complete error message.

Comment: i have posted logcat. help me out please

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 74649612 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM
```

Somewhere in your app, you have a `LinearLayout` on which you placed an `android:background` attribute (or possibly something else) that points to a drawable resource. That drawable resource is **much too large**. The decompressed image would be 74,649,612 bytes. This is the equivalent of an 8,640 x 8,640 pixel iamge. There are no mainstream devices with a screen anywhere near that resolution.

Please reduce the resolution of this image. And, if you did something like put it in `res/drawable/`, prepare different versions of this image for different screen densities (e.g., `res/drawable-xhdpi/`), as the automatic resampling of the image is exacerbating your problem.